# My SQL error #1015 - Can't lock file (errno: 165 - Table is read only) innodb engine only

Tags: mysql, innodb

My SQL error

```
#1015 - Can't lock file (errno: 165 - Table is read only)
```

innodb engine only

first the MySql start to stop work and needed restart almost every day

then it's start to work in read only mode

MySQL version is 5.6

my.cnf content

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table=1
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
max_allowed_packet=268435456
innodb_buffer_pool_size=134217728
innodb_force_recovery=4
```

my log

```
140819 05:48:57 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/server1.mohdev.com.pid ended
140819 05:48:58 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2014-08-19 05:48:59 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2014-08-19 05:48:59 9876 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-08-19 05:48:59 9876 [Note] InnoDB: Started in read only mode
2014-08-19 05:48:59 9876 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2014-08-19 05:48:59 9876 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-08-19 05:48:59 9876 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2014-08-19 05:48:59 9876 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-08-19 05:48:59 9876 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2014-08-19 05:48:59 9876 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-08-19 05:48:59 9876 [Note] InnoDB: Disabling background IO write threads.
2014-08-19 05:48:59 9876 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2014-08-19 05:48:59 9876 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-08-19 05:48:59 9876 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-08-19 05:48:59 9876 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.17 started; log sequence number 2706168115
2014-08-19 05:48:59 9876 [Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 4 !!!
2014-08-19 05:48:59 9876 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2014-08-19 05:48:59 9876 [Note] IPv6 is not available.
2014-08-19 05:48:59 9876 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
2014-08-19 05:48:59 9876 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2014-08-19 05:48:59 9876 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2014-08-19 05:48:59 9876 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.17'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2014-08-19 05:49:22 9876 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table '"epl_mdb"."jpxsqzjy_options"' in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 1156.
2014-08-19 05:49:22 9876 [Warning] InnoDB: Allocated tablespace 1156, old maximum was 0
2014-08-19 05:49:22 9876 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table '"epl_mdb"."jpxsqzjy_posts"' in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 584.
2014-08-19 05:49:23 9876 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table '"epl_mdb"."jpxsqzjy_term_taxonomy"' in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 591.
2014-08-19 05:54:26 9876 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

2014-08-19 05:54:26 9876 [Note] Giving 1 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2014-08-19 05:54:26 9876 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2014-08-19 05:54:26 9876 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2014-08-19 05:54:28 9876 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 1 remaining clients
2014-08-19 05:54:28 9876 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 3  user: 'leechprotect'
```

i tried to add

```
innodb-read-only=0
```

in my.cnf but no luck
any suggestions
thanks

Comment: `innodb_force_recovery is set to 4` => only set it to something if there's something to recover, set it to 0 again, and restart and see if that has helped the initial problem you were solving in the first place, don't leave it running in recovery mode. It could very well be those 3 tables mentioned are permanently damaged / unrecoverable.

Comment: some how those 3 tables was not damaged and every thing works fine for now

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have this in your config:

```
innodb_force_recovery=4
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html says:

> As of 5.6.6, an innodb_force_recovery setting of 4 or greater places InnoDB in read-only mode.

That option is something you'd do only while trying to extract data from a corrupted tablespace. You should remove that option from you my.cnf and restart.

Comment: yes of curse you are right thanks i just remove the line from my config and every thing is working again

Comment: It's solved for me.

innodb_force_recovery=4 

remove the option from your my.ini and restart.